# WishList Members plug in for wordpress not finding protected posts

Tags: wordpress

I was having trouble with the WishList Members plugin that's already installed on an installation of wordpress I'm working on. I built a new custom theme, but the posts that are members only don't show up after I log in. It says "Posts not found." If I switch back to the previous theme all of the content shows up with no problem and I noted that all of the URLs are the same. Just seeing if I need to add in the registration key to the new theme or if there was something else I was missing.

Thanks in advance for any help!
-Frank

Answer (score 0):

So I more or less figured out the answer to this. If you're making your own theme in wordpress there's a lot that goes on behind the scenes with the prepackaged themes. Basically, if you just turn your custom theme into a child theme of one of these themes yours will inherit all of the functionality needed for plugins that don't seem to work right. I hope this helps someone down the road if ever they have the same problem as me.

-Frank